# JavaScript ClearInterval button doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I've reviewed the other `clearInterval` posts here for a clue as to why my code isn't functioning as intended. Despite my best efforts, I still can't get `clearInterval` to stop my count.

I'm trying to do something simple: have a count, increase by one until the stop button is pushed.

I have tried different, and incorrect variables, but I cannot find a working solution.

```html
    <p>Count Up:</p>
    <p id="count">1</p>
    <button onclick="clearInterval(current)">Stop</button>
    <script>
      var current = 1;
      function animateValue(id) {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
        setInterval(function () {
          current++;
          obj.innerHTML = current;
        }, 1000);
      }
      animateValue("count");
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)? That would be a good start for “best efforts”. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: You need to pass the return value of `setInterval` into `clearInterval` and not some arbitrary number.

Comment: @SebastianSimon—I think the OP is just an example. For that it's just fine. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value returned by `setInterval` in a variable and pass that as the parameter to `clearInterval` instead of `counter`:

```html
<p>Count Up:</p>
<p id="count">1</p>
<button onclick="clearInterval(interval)">Stop</button>
<script>
  var interval;
  var current = 1;
  function animateValue(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      current++;
      obj.innerHTML = current;
    }, 1000);
  }
  animateValue("count");
</script>
```